# How can i add an attribute to a tag that is created in runtime

Tags: aem, sightly

So I need to add the attribute `media="all"` to these two link tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/etc.clientlibs/farmers/clientlibs/clientlib-libraries.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/etc.clientlibs/farmers/clientlibs/clientlib-base.css" type="text/css">
```

but my local HTML file is configured as:

```
<sly data-sly-use.clientlib="/libs/granite/sightly/templates/clientlib.html">
<sly data-sly-call="${clientlib.css @ categories=['farmers.new.libraries','farmers.new.base']}" /> </sly>
```

It is a language called HTL, HTML Template Language. There's a way to add attributes via HTL but you need to create a whole java class in the back end and call it, it's a headache.

I want to know if I can add some javascript to append the attribute `media="all"` to the link tags to these specific CSS file path.

I was thinking of putting both paths inside a div and then with javascript find that div and append an attribute to each link tag inside that div.

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
var element = document.createElement('link');
element.rel = 'stylesheet';
element.type = 'text/css';
element.href = '/etc.clientlibs/farmers/clientlibs/clientlib-libraries.css';

// Here's the magic
element.media = 'all';
head.appendChild(element, head.firstChild);
setTimeout(function () {
  element.media = 'all';
});
```

A script tag is being created and I want to add `async=""` to this:

```
<!--/* Include Context Hub */-->
<sly data-sly-call="${clientlib.js @ categories='granite.utils'}" />
<sly data-sly-resource="${'contexthub' @ resourceType='granite/contexthub/components/contexthub'}" />
```

Comment: Why would you want to add media=“all” ? That is the default value for media attribute. As for adding the media attribute, you’ll have to do something similar to what I did here: https://github.com/ahmed-musallam/aem-clientlib-async to add the attribute. Here is the main code: https://github.com/ahmed-musallam/aem-clientlib-async/blob/master/async-clientlib/ClientLibUseObject.java

Comment: also take a look at link rewriter/transformer service. https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/aem63_link_rewriter.html

Comment: ok so i have some script tags i want to add attributes like async or defer do i have to write a whole java class for that ?

Comment: i want to add async = "" in this tag that will be created into a script tag `<!--/* Include Context Hub */-->
<sly data-sly-call="${clientlib.js @ categories='granite.utils'}" />
<sly data-sly-resource="${'contexthub' @ resourceType='granite/contexthub/components/contexthub'}" />`

Comment: @DavidArriaga please look at my comment. The code is in that repo with explanation for async attribute. But your question was regarding media attribute...

Comment: @AhmedMusallam Yes I understand, but in short do i need to write a whole java class in order to implements attributes inside these task. Reading the documentation seems to be a task on itself and very busy with many other task. But thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks fine. But your code has a mistake. You should get the first element from the collection to access `<head></head>` element.

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
```

Comment: Hello that code is not what im using its just an example . I dont know if it works or not, my question about the special data-sly-call tags, those become into normal html tags with hrefs

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do that? Just do not use the clientlib mechanism. Most frontend developers will use their IDEs to build and minify CSS and JS anyway so there is not much to be lost if you import those artifacts at buildtime and add the  tags in your code directly in the way you need them.